# An "IF" Excel formula that meets criteria of above and below cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, countif

I'm designing a poker training spreadsheet and I've been trying to work out a formula that highlights each row as you progress through the questions with a "-->" arrow.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

My goal is to insert a "-->" on a row where the previous question has been answered (either "yes" or "no"), but also to instead insert "" if another question in the column is currently highlighted with a "-->" - this way it should smoothly run continuously and no two rows should be highlighted at one time.

The first question was simple enough: I used

```
=IF(AND(N2="", G3<>"-->"), "-->", "")
```

I tried to use the following formula on the remaining rows but it didn't work for some reason

```
=IF(AND(N2="Yes", (COUNTIF(G4:$G$49, "<>"%"-->")>0)), "-->", " ")
```

This was initially a test to get the functionality working if each answer was correct, which I would then change to 'if the answer is "yes" or "no".

Comment: also please ignore that there is 0 outs and the correct answer is to call - this is just a test

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly,

this should do the trick:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($M$2:$M$20,"<>"&"")+2=ROW(),"-->","")
```

Comment: Thanks this is definitely a step closer - I've changed it to: 

> =IF(COUNTIF($N$2:$N$20,"Yes")+2=ROW(),"-->","")

Messes up a little if previous answers are deleted but that's fine = now I just need the criteria to be if $N$2:$N$20 is "yes" OR "no"

Comment: This is exactly what a function provided does, I would suggest create a data validation drop down list of yes and no for N column...